# Não consigo encontrar este (error expected declaration or statement at end of input)

Tags: c

Sou novo nessa ramo de programação, estou fazendo um projeto, assistindo um curso e tentando inserir o que aprendo no meu programa, o principal erro que está dando agora é "error expected declaration or statement at end of input", sei que é um erro simples, mas realmente não consegui encontrar, por falta de tempo, também tentei empregar um sistema de buscas no case 2 que vi em outro código, não sei se fiz certo, sei que há muitos erros neste código, caso possam me ajudar, estou bem dispostO a aprender, segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>//Biblioteca padrão
#include <stdlib.h> //Necessário para system("pause");

int numero; //Variavel global

int main(void) { //função principal do programa
//Inicio da função main

char op; // para usar o do while

do {   //retornar caso a opção desejada não seja valida

    //Criando uma Struct
    struct professores_cursinho //professores_cursinho passa a ser um tipo de dados

    {
        //Abrindo e inserindo coleção de variaveis a struct
        char Nome[40], Disciplina[30];
        int Idade, Carga_Horaria;
        float Salario;
    }; //Final da definição da struct

    struct professores_cursinho Professor[20];// "Professor" agora é uma variável do tipo professores_cursinho, ele possui todas as variáveis que contem na struct

    printf("\n ---------- Escolha uma opcao: --------- \n");
    printf("1 - Cadastrar Professor\n");
    printf("2 - Buscar Professor\n");
    printf("3 - Sair do Programa\n\n");
    printf("Digite sua opcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero); //Mandar para variavel global "numero"

    switch(numero) {
        case 1:

            printf("\n---------- Cadastro de Professor ----------\n\n\n");

            printf("Nome do Professor: ");
            fflush(stdin);//Para limpar o buffer do teclado

            /* Usaremos o comando fgets() para ler string, no caso do nome
            do professor e a disciplina
            fgets(variavel, tamanho da string, entrada)
            como estamos lendo com o teclado a entrada é stdin(entrada padrão)
            porém, em outro caso, a entrada também pode ser arquivo*/

            fgets(Professor[20].Nome, 40, stdin);

            printf("Nome da Disciplina: ");
            fflush(stdin);//Para limpar o buffer do teclado
            fgets(Professor[20].Disciplina, 30, stdin);

            printf("Informe a Idade: ");
            scanf("%d", &Professor[20].Idade);

            printf("Informe a Carga Horaria: ");
            scanf("%d", &Professor[20].Carga_Horaria);

            printf("Informe o Salario: ");
            scanf("%f", &Professor[20].Salario);

            printf("\n\n---------- Lendo os dados da struct ----------\n\n");
            printf("Nome: %s", Professor[20].Nome);
            printf("Disciplina: %s ", Professor[20].Disciplina);
            printf("Idade: %d ", Professor[20].Idade);
            printf("Carga Horaria: %d\n ", Professor[20].Carga_Horaria);
            printf("Salario: %.2f\n ", Professor[20].Salario);

            system("cls"); //para limpar a tela e retornar ao menu principal
            break;

        case 2:
            //Inserir aqui o sistema de busca
            printf("\nDigite o nome do professor: ");
            int posicao = 5;
            char auxiliar[20];
            scanf("%s", auxiliar);


            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < Professor; i++) {
                if (strcmp(auxiliar, Professor[20].Nome[i]) == 0) {
                    posicao = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (posicao != 5) {

                printf("NOME: %s\n", Professor[20].Nome);
                printf("DISCIPLINA: %s\n", Professor[20].Disciplina);
                printf("IDADE: %d\n", Professor[20].Idade);
                printf("CARGA HORARIA: %d\n", Professor[20].Carga_Horaria);
                printf("SALARIO: %f\n", Professor[20].Salario);

            } else {

                printf("\n----- PROFESSOR NAO ENCONTRADO! -----\n\n");
            }

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("\n---------- OBRIGADO POR UTILIZAR O PROGRAMA :) ----------\n\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("DIGITE UMA OPCAO VALIDA");
            break;

    }
    while (op != 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: poderia formatar o código para melhor exibição? É possível editar a pergunta para fazer as correções.

Comment: Estou tendo dificuldades em inserir o código, mas formatei, cortou a parte até int main(void)

Comment: Sim, basta endentar corretamente, existe um botão na interface para facilitar a formatação. O nome do botão é `code`.

Comment: Certo, consegui.

Comment: Você esqueceu de adicionar um `}` para fechar o `switch` (ou o `do` dependendo da perspectiva). Então, antes da linha `while (op != 3);` adicione uma chave e o seu programa vai compilar.

Comment: A parte isso, o seu programa  tem alguns erros que vão impedir ele de  funcionar. Por exemplo, você declara o array `Professor` para conter 20 elementos, e durante todo o programa a única posição do array que você acessa é a 21ª com `Professor[20]`, isso não apenas corrompe a memória como faz com que o seu sistema de cadastro não funcione.  Usar `fflush(stdin);` é simplesmente um erro. `i < Professor` está errado já que `Professor` não é um inteiro. Sugestão: não é incomum a primeira versão de um código ter erros, então, use essa oportunidade para aprender a debugar um programa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você esta tendo problema de sintaxe. Deve estar esquecendo um `;` ou `}` em algum lugar de seu programa, recomendo que o leia com paciência e se atenha a endentação. Por exemplo

```
int main(){
    do{
        switch(numero){
            case 1:
            break;
        }
    }while(op != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

recomendo usar o visual studio code com puglins de C/C++.